# Знаки, закрывающие прямую речь внутри авторских слов

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> Я тогда попросила его взять хорошей музыки в дорогу, и он сказал: «О!
>   У меня такая есть», – так бодро, что я испугалась.

Запятая после кавычек не нужна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что после кавычек запятая не нужна.
**Я тогда попросила его взять хорошей музыки в дорогу, и он сказал: «О! У меня такая есть» – так бодро, что я испугалась.**

[В справочнике Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=442):
после прямой речи ставится тире в случае отсутствия знака препинания на месте разрыва вводящих слов автора: *Перебарывая неловкость, он пробормотал студенческую остроту: «У меня бабушка корью заболела» — и хотел придать начатому разговору непринужденную легковесность* (Бонд.).

Answer (score 1):

**Я тогда попросила его взять хорошей музыки в дорогу, и он сказал «О! У меня такая есть»  так бодро, что я испугалась.**

Пояснение

Здесь лучше оформить прямую речь как член предложения (без двоеточия, только с кавычками).

Пауза перед "Так бодро" явно отсутствует, тесная связь наречия  с глаголом.

Ссылки на Розенталя или Лопатина здесь не подходит (у них предложения другой структуры).

Еще вариант: *Я тогда попросила его взять  **хорошую музыку**  в дорогу, и он так **оживленно сказал**: «О! У меня такая есть», что я испугалась.*

(Двоеточие всё-таки хотелось бы поставить).

Comment: Я тогда попросила его взять хорошей музыки в дорогу, и он так бодро сказал: «О! У меня такая есть», что я испугалась.